# WPF - Can StringFormat be bound to a property?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, string-formatting

Given a WPF text box, as an example:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=blahProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat=\{0:yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss\}}"/>
```

Could the StringFormat I've got there instead be bound to an underlying property string? - i.e. could the "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss" be provided by a property on the View (or ViewModel) instead of being hard-coded in the xaml?

Comment: I'm assuming "blahProperty" is a datetime that you want to format.
That being said, you could create a seperate string property in your datacontext which would return the formatted string.

Comment: yes, that would be an option. It would create a lot of additional complexity though (the formatted string property would have to update blah every time it was changed in the UI, NotifyPropertyChanged would be more complex. etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a `{Binding}` cannot be set on the `StringFormat` property of the `Binding` because `StringFormat` is not a dependency property.

You can only bind to a `DependencyProperty` of a `DependencyObject`, i.e. the target property of a binding must be a dependency property.

You may set it to the the value of static property though:

```
StringFormat={x:Static local:MainWindow.StaticProperty}}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a helpful alternative.